# ¿Hay alguna manera de aplicar un xslt dos xml con tags distintos?

Tags: visual-studio, xml, servicio, xsl, xslt

Me explico mejor, la duda que tengo es si puedo aplicar un XSLT a dos XML que tienen ciertos tags con nombres distintos.

Un ejemplo

*primer Xml*

```
<Persona>
<Nombre>Sebastián</Nombre>
</Persona>
```

*segundo XML*

```
<Persona>
<PrimerNombre>Claudio</PrimerNombre>
</Persona>
```

*El resultado seria después de aplicar el XSLT*

```
Persona : Sebastián 
Persona : Claudio
```